# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14),

Tags: mysql, sql

Creating a search engine for my website with the help of Sphider

but when creating the MySQL database tables the following error message showed

Error
SQL query:

```
create table query_log (
query varchar(255),
time timestamp(14),
elapsed float(2),
results int)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14),
>       elapsed float(2),
>       results int)' at line 3

Comment: What is the 14 in `timestamp(14)` supposed to mean?  I don't think you can define a length/precision of timestamp columns.

Comment: Are you just making it up as you go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies with the number following your timestamp declaration. MySQL documentation says of the timestamp type:

> the display width is fixed at 19 characters, and the format is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

So, your code can be fixed by making the following modification:

```
create table query_log (
    query varchar(255),
    time timestamp,
    elapsed float(2),
    results int
)
```

As far as the number "14" goes, it's unclear where you were going with that. Does the project you are working on require that a timestamp of a specific length? If so, it might be best to use another data type, or to convert the timestamp to the desired format *after* it is pulled from the database.

I am new on StackExchange, so I hope that I've adequately answered the question. Please let me know if I can help with anything else!

Comment: Your alteration seems to work fine, presumably the error was a typo in sphiders code - part of a flexible search box and engine I am trying to develop for my site. Not being a programming expert I am not always able to detect when code supplied is wrong or has bugs. Thank you for your help